# Obfuscated pyarmor wheel contains no files

Tags: python-wheel, pyarmor

I've successfully obfuscated a project using the command

`pyarmor gen --recursive -i src`

The outcome

```
tree dist/
dist/
├── pyarmor_runtime_006080
│        ├── __init__.py
│        └── pyarmor_runtime.so
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.rst
└── src
    ├── Application.py
```

(I copied `pyproject.toml` and `README.rst` to `dist` otherwise the following command )fails.

Next I'd like to build a wheel from the obfuscated source and toward that end I run the command:

`python3 -m build --skip-dependency-check --no-isolation --wheel dist/`

Unfortunately, the wheel has no files in it:

```
unzip -l dist/dist/app-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Archive:  dist/dist/app-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  1980-01-01 00:00   src/py.typed
      138  2016-01-01 00:00   app-1.5.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt
       83  2016-01-01 00:00   app-1.5.0.dist-info/WHEEL
     6385  2016-01-01 00:00   app-1.5.0.dist-info/METADATA
      360  2016-01-01 00:00   app-1.5.0.dist-info/RECORD
---------                     -------
     6966                     5 files
```

The only thing that stands out is that `pyproject.toml` (which I did not originally create) contains a similar entry:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "app"
...
include = ["src/py.typed", "src/pyarmor_runtime_006080", ".so"]
packages = [
    { include = "src" }
]
```